# Can Artificial Intelligence be used to find out reasonable conjectures or even to turn them into theorems by discovering a proof?

Tags: soft-question, research, computer-assisted-proofs

Can Artificial Intelligence be used to find out reasonable conjectures or even to turn them into theorems by discovering a proof ?  If yes, and after a proof is indeed found through AI, can one instruct the AI program to explain how did it found the proof ?

Comment: Of course it can be used... I'm even afraid that some day robots can discover mathematics that will be beyond comprehension of humanity..

Comment: See also http://theconversation.com/will-computers-replace-humans-in-mathematics-60168

Comment: Also interesting http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2015/03/computers_proving_mathematical_theorems_how_artificial_intelligence_could.html

Answer (score 1):

These kind of AI already exist. [Here is a related wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving)

There are however some problems... what do we mean by a "Reasonable conjecture" and what do we mean by "exaplaining a proof"?

The Theorem provers can allways give you an explanation, however these are usually 1000 lines of long logical formulas, which in some sence is quite impossible to read through, or at least not what you expect when you want and explanation.

Which questions one should prove and what is a "reasonable conjecture" is a very philosophical question. If you ask top researchers for "pointless research" in their field, they will probably be able to point such out, but that does not mean that the "pointless research" is not new and is not true.

Now what you probably wanted to know is if all mathematical research can currently be swapped by good AIs, where the answer is obviously no. However, in time...

Comment: IMHO, not even in the far future. There are immense problems. Proving or creating theorems is not like playing chess or CGI rendering. We don't know how our mind works and we probably will never know. I read and strongly advice you to read *John  Horgan. The Undiscovered Mind: How the Human Brain Defies Replication, Medication and Explanation. New York: Touchstone.(1999)*

Comment: @Raffaele You are a pessimist (or optimist - depends on point of view) but looking how fast  robots and AI are developing lately, it is rather impossible that mathematics would be one of the domains of human activity when robots never will not  enter, hard to say where they will have an advantage over people - probably in analyzing big data structures.. do they coin their definitions ? (good definitions are as important as good theorems) and conjectures? , we will see...

Comment: @Widawensen You, young people will see. I am $60$... soon all my memories  *will be lost in time, like tears in rain.*